# Two-way databind on a forEach?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an object of products. The products i get from a resource (`Product`), store in a factory (`productsStore`), and iterate through in a controller.

In another controller, i want to either empty of refresh products via `productsStore.empty();` or `productsStore.get();`. But either of them does nothing. Meaning my forEach, below, is not being run again, and the list not updated.
What am i doing wrong?

Controller:

```
vm.products = productsStore.get();
vm.products.$promise.then(function (data) {
    angular.forEach(vm.products, function (child) {
        //. some code
    )};
)};
```

Factory:

```
myApp.factory('productsStore', function ($http, $q, Product) {
    var products = "";

    var get = function () {
        return products = Product.query();
    };

    var empty = function () {
        return products = {};
    };

    // Bind products
    products = get();

    return {
        get: get,
        empty: empty
    };
});
```

Resource:

```
myApp.factory('Product', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('http://api.com/api/products/:id', { id: '@id' }, {
        update: {
            method: 'PUT'
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Promise resolves only once.

Answer (score 0):

try to loop through the data you get after the promise is resolved, otherwise it's a rather useless variable.

```
angular.forEach(data, function(child) {
  //...do something with the child
});
```

Also, you have a typo, that I'm not sure you have in your actual code. In your controller, end of block should be }) and not )}

Comment: I tried removing the promise check completly, but to no change. Still nothing gets updated :-/

Comment: what do you mean by promise check? you shouldn't remove anything beside replacing "vm.products" with "data" in the "forEach" block.

Comment: Ahh, sorry. Misunderstood you. Changed it now, but still nothing. Hmm